# I got an error: Use of unresolved identifier 'UINotificationFeedbackGenerator'

Tags: swift, uikit, haptic-feedback

When instantiating 'UINotificationFeedbackGenerator' for haptic feedback, I get this compiler error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'UINotificationFeedbackGenerator'

This is how I instantiate it:

```
   let hapticNotificationFeedback = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
   hapticNotificationFeedback?.prepare()
   var hapticImpactFeedback = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium)
```

I am instantiating this in a view controller extension in a separate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a view controller class extension file, you need to import UIKit in this file as well

> import UIKit